Jmeter html report is showing 'Assertion failed' only instead of actual error message in load test report
I am using Apache jmeter version 5.6.3 and facing a weird problem.
When I am converting the jtl file to html report, In 'Type of error' column of 'Errors' section It is showing 'Assertion failed' only instead of actual error message in load test report. While in smoke test report it is showing actual message like,
"Test failed: text expected not to contain /reception id not found/"
Due to this issue, If there are two or more response assertions in the script, It is merging all the response assertion errors in html report into one and i am not able to find out like what all errors I am getting in my load test. Please help !
refer below snapshot from load test report,


I cannot reproduce your issue using clean vanilla JMeter 5.6.3 and the following command:
jmeter -n -t ../extras/Test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard


So most probably you changed Results file configuration somehow, please inspect JMeter .properties files and look for any eventual overrides.

Hi Ivan, Found the issue, but still looking for the solution or any workaround. Issue seems to be with FilterResults.bat tool. Actually I am using this tool to remove the rampup time from my jtl file. But it is removing the failure message and URL as well from the newly created jtl file, due to which HTML report is not showing any failure message but only 'Assertion failed'. Is there any known issue with the tool ?

What prevents you from setting jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date and jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date properties instead of using a 3rd-party tool? More information: Reporting configuration and Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide. In order to get help with plugins ask a question in JMeter Plugins Support Forum
